# Basic IBAction function questions with textfield and NSPopUpButtonCell title

Tags: objective-c, nspopupbutton

I'm just getting the basics down for objective c. 
I want to create a textfield whose string is the same as the title of the dropbox cell I choose. 
I have:

```
- (IBAction)dropbox:(id)sender{
NSPopUpButtonCell *sampleCell = [sender selectedCell];
[self setWord:@"%@",sampleCell.title]; 

[sampleCell release];
}
```

where word is declared as

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *word;
@synthesize word = _word;
```

apparently I'm not allowed to have the placeholder argument when using [self setWord:]. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you haven't gained ownership of `sampleCell` so you should not be releasing it. This will trigger an exception. Also, you're setting an NSTextField to a string.

This is what i would do:

```
- (IBAction)dropbox:(id)sender{
NSPopUpButtonCell *sampleCell = [sender selectedCell];
[self.word setTextValue:sampleCell.title]; 
}
```

Comment: excellent. 
thats the correct syntax, i needed no hardcoded string+placeholder since sampleCell.title is a string. 
and yes I guess because i never alloced I don't release. thank you